# looping an array in javascript and doubling the numbers based on condition

Tags: javascript

I am a new in programming so bear me, i find a problem and my question is 
how to make that  in array using javascript that each element preceded by six is multiplied by 2 even if the element multiplied is 6 the condition still remain and avoiding to apply the condition if the multiplied is 3 and make Six  ?

```js
var arr = [6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == 6) {
    arr[i + 1] *= 2
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

i expected the output to be

```
var arr= [6,12,12,12,6,2]
```

Comment: Do you mean preceded instead of followed ? At least that is what the expected result indicates.

Comment: @Titus I’m almost certain OP means preceded. Otherwise the first 6 would be doubled.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: yes you have got it, it was preceded instead of followed

Answer (score 2):

You could loop the array in the reverse order

```js
var arr = [6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2];

for (var i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (arr[i] == 6) {
    arr[i + 1] *= 2
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

I'm starting `i` at `arr.length - 2` because the last number needs to be ignored. Otherwise, if the last number is `6`, `arr[i+1] *= 2` will add an extra `NaN` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map` and check if the previous element is `6` then return the value multiplied by `2` else just return the value

```js
var arr = [6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2];

var newarr = arr.map((x,i) => arr[i-1] == 6 ? x*2 :x)

console.log(newarr)
```

Comment: I am voting that this should be the correct answer, as it is the most up-to-date solution for the problem and uses the array functions everybody else seems to ignore.

Comment: @QuentinAlbert Using the higher-order array functions isn't necessarily the best solution. For instance, using it here creates an entirely new array, whereas adiga's solution works in-place, taking the same time to run but without requiring a whole new array to be allocated.

Answer (score 0):

When you do your first loop, you change the second item to be 12, right? It's no longer equal to 6, so it doesn't change the 3rd item. the 3rd is still 6, so it changes the 4th item and so on and so forth. So you if you have an array filled with 6, it changes every other 6.

If you want your expected output, I'd suggest making a temp copy of your array, checking the original array, changing the temp array, then returning the temp array.

edit:

```
var arr=[6,6,6,6,3,2];
var temparr = arr.slice();

for( var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(arr[i]==6){
      temparr[i + 1] = temparr[i + 1] * 2;
   }
}
```

arr.slice() makes a separate copy of the array. Without it, any change to temparr would change arr as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should map that array. What Array.prototype.map does, it takes a function and applies that function to all the array elements, and creates a new array from what that function returns. It passes three arguments to that function (the element, the index of the element and the initial array).

```
let newArr = arr.map(function(x, index, array) {
    if (index == 0) return x;

    if (array[index-1] == 6) return x*2

    return x;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you already have... i made a little modification to as below

```js
let arr = [6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2];
let prev = arr[0];
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let current = arr[i]
  if (prev == 6) {
    arr[i] *= 2
  }
  prev = current
}

console.log(arr)
```

The idea you had was to change the next element in the array but the problem is when it comes to the next element, you had changed it to another value... there are many ways to achieve this. One of them is shown above.

1. It remembers the previous value (the original value)
2. If previous value is 6, multiply current value by 2
3. Set previous value to current value
4. repeat step 2 until it is done

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 2];
var ar2 = [arr[0]];

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i - 1] == 6) {
    ar2.push(arr[i] * 2)
  } else {
    ar2.push(arr[i])
  }
}

console.log(ar2)
```